# Calling Kotlin methods from C++ with JNI

Tags: c++, kotlin, java-native-interface

I have following problem:

I have android project with c++ core and kotlin ui. At the moment cross-language bridging is implemented through jni, which works with auto-generated interface and structures in java, that are imported or implemented in Kotlin. I want to get rid of Java in that construction and work directly with generated kotlin code, but I have following problem:

I have following data structure:

```
class CommonParams
    (var deviceIds: HashMap<String, String>?,
  var device: String?,
  var machineName: String?,
  var onlyAccount: Boolean?,
  var currentClient: Int?,
  var appClientId: String?,
  var appSecret: String?,
  var needHierarchy: Boolean?,
  var originDeviceId: String?)
{}
```

When it was in Java I got its constructor as:

```
<init>(Ljava/util/HashMap;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Boolean;Ljava/lang/Int;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Boolean;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Now I'm getting exception, that there is no such method. I think that problem is with HashMap, but I'm not sure. I've already tried to replace Ljava/util/HashMap with Lkotlin/collections/HashMap, with no result. What will be proper way to import this method from Kotlin through JNI? Or is there any documentation on difference between Java and Kotlin JNI?

Comment: `Ljava/lang/Int` <-- Don't you mean `Ljava/lang/Integer`?

Comment: Yes, it was the problem, thanks